# Django REST Framework - List items with possible actions

Tags: hyperlink, django-rest-framework, action, serialization

I would like to extend the standard `ListAPIView` by adding allowed actions to each item so that the JSON returned on `GET /books/` would approximately look as follows:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "name": "Animal Farm",
    "author": "George Orwell",
    "actions": [
      "detail": {
        "method": "GET"
        "uri": "/books/1"
      },
      "remove": {
        "method": "DELETE"
        "uri": "/books/1"
      }
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

By having such an "action list", I can easily tell the frontend which actions are currently allowed so it can e. g. include only buttons for those actions.

I went through the DRF docs and could not find a similar functionality. Shall I write it from scratch or is there a 3rd party plugin that could possibly help me? And when writing this from scratch, how would you design (=where to write the code of) such a feature?

Answer (score 1):

DRF has support for that when you use the `OPTIONS` method, you can find more info [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/).
You could take a look into how this `SimpleMetadata` function creates the list of actions and either base yourself on it to write yours from scratch, or just [find a way to call it to render the action list](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/#creating-schema-endpoints).

Comment: This is something a bit different - it describes the fields of the model. Instead, I want to specify allowed actions on each object. Imagine a booking app, you can only book a hotel if it is not full. So those hotels which are full will be listed, but the action "book" will not be present.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if there is such plugin in DRF (maybe something for serializers?).

If writing from scratch, you should override your `get()` method `ListAPIView` (or `list()` method of `mixins.ListModelMixin`)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add a `SerializerMethodField` to the serializer?

Comment: @karlosss - it's hard for me say, because I don't know how your models look like and full logic of your "action list"

Comment: Ideally, this shall be completely independent of the models. The only thing which needs to be included somewhere is the logic which decides which actions are allowed.